Any utility to convert from SVG/PDF/PS to MP (metapost)?
Hi folks do you know any utilities to convert from SVG/PS/PDF to MP?
I know about tools that do the opposite but in my case I need to convert some schematic graphics I made into pure metapost.
I exhumed an old GUI application Metagraf but besides being very clunky it is too much buggy and it is not possible working with it.
Thanks!

ConTeXt can include and convert SVG graphics to MetaPost. When you add \enabletrackers[metapost.svg.result] at the start of the document you get the generated MetaPost code in the terminal, e.g.
\enabletrackers[metapost.svg.result]

% https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/svg-tutorial-learn-to-code-images/

\startbuffer[svgtest]
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
  <polygon points="0,0 80,120 -80,120" fill="#234236" />
  <polygon points="0,-40 60,60 -60,60" fill="#0C5C4C" />
  <polygon points="0,-80 40,0 -40,0" fill="#38755B" />
  <rect x="-20" y="120" width="40" height="30" fill="brown" />
</svg>
\stopbuffer

\starttext
\includesvgbuffer[svgtest]
\stoptext

shows the following listing in the terminal (and log file)
metapost        > svg > result graphic:
    draw image (
      fill (((0,0)--(80,-120)--(-80,-120)--cycle)&&cycle)
        withcolor svgcolor(0.137,0.259,0.212)
      ;
      fill (((0,40)--(60,-60)--(-60,-60)--cycle)&&cycle)
        withcolor svgcolor(0.047,0.361,0.298)
      ;
      fill (((0,80)--(40,0)--(-40,0)--cycle)&&cycle)
        withcolor svgcolor(0.22,0.459,0.357)
      ;
      fill (unitsquare xyscaled (40,30) shifted (-20,-150))
        withcolor svgcolor(0.647,0.165,0.165)
      ;
    currentpicture := currentpicture shifted (100,-100);
    clip currentpicture to (unitsquare xyscaled (200,-200));
    ) ;

Be aware ConTeXt uses its own MetaFun extension when it generates the converted MetaPost code.

Having MetaFun generating the code is not ideal but it is something, thanks!

I used a SVG code extracted from an Inkscape file cleaned with Scour, but it did not worked out...

@freezr You can try to show you problematic SVG graphic on the ConTeXt mailing list.

Eventually I realized I had to use the latest version, with the latest version I was able to get the conversion on the logs! Thank you very much this really has been a great help for me!
